# hosted website in IIS on a local server with localhost\website retur to Windows Admin Center

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019

Trying to connect to my IIS website created in a Windows server 2019. But each time it's a default page "Windows Admin Center".
My IIS website is "http://localhost/MIO" each time it tries to navigate to a browser, a connect me to "Windows Admin Center" with this address "http://localhos/"

I try different web browser and I try with http and https

Comment: From which machine did you open the browser? The same machine with IIS installed, or another?

Comment: yes the same machine

Comment: tested from other connected server, it require the user and PW then give the same page "Windows Admin Center"

Comment: Sounds like Windows Admin Center hooks to Windows HTTP API and blocks all access to the related URLs, https://superuser.com/questions/1426442/run-website-on-iis-in-server-with-windows-admin-center-installed so that your IIS sites won't work. Must you run IIS sites on this machine? You might try to use another machine for web site hosting (which is very common in a corporate setup).

Comment: How did you configure your website? usually localhost does not redirect, please post more details information about your website.

Comment: Issue solved by uninstalling the Windows Admin Cente the I run those two command netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443
netsh http delete urlacl url=https://+:443/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by uninstalling the Windows Admin Center and executing the following two commands:

1. `netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443`
2. `netsh http delete urlacl url=https://+:443/`